# Get archive of posts separated by taxonomies and subtaxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy

I'm making a website that lists hotels by region and sub-regions.

I made a custom post type called Hotels and a custom Taxonomy called Regions. I've inserted countries as parent regions and states as child regions.

I tought it would be simple to make this query but i'm hitting the wall. In technical language that's what i'm trying to do:

Get an archive of custom type posts separated by taxonomies and subtaxonomies.

[image: post query]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Artur, are you trying to list hotels on country & state archive pages? So for example `http://example.com/mexico` would list 20 hotels in Mexico and `http://example.com/mexico/durango` would list 5 hotels which are there in Durango ? Please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: Hi there. http://example.com/hotels/mexico would list 20 hotels separated by states. So it would show durango hotels and 15 more. And http://examples.com/hotels would list all hotels separated by country and by states.